# How can we login multiple account on same browser

Tags: authentication

I am creating an app with Node.js express to display social media feeds using their API. I am using FACEBOOK, TWITTER, INSTAGRAM. When I click on any social media icon, a popup window is appearing  to login. After logging in all of them. I clicked a button to display feeds. This is working good for single account. Now I want to login multiple account for every social media. But whenever I clicked another social media icon to login .I saw there is already logged in.

For example I click Facebook icon to login . After appearing model window I fill up my username(jrajput315) and password. After logging in this account, I want to login some other Facebook account. And I click Facebook icon to login again. But I see (jrajput315) is already logged in there.

Comment: Can you post your code, what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are already logged in to Facebook from one account, Facebook uses a sign-in cookie to keep you logged in. Until this cookie is flushed out, you cannot login through another facebook account on the same browser in the same session.
- I guess similar practice happens with few other web-apps, if I am not mistaken.